# Detecting UEFI option in BIOS

Tags: uefi

How can I tell if a specific machine has SecureBoot/UEFI as an option in the BIOS short of booting into the BIOS and visually inspecting it? Is there a way to see this information in Windows even if the option is currently disabled? Note: on Windows 7

Comment: "in the BIOS" you mean the _firmware_. UEFI is the replacement for BIOS. HWinfo is what I've historically used to check this. Windows itself might have an , but all I found so far was a way to check the _current_ session's boot mode, as you noted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It (UEFI support) should be reported in SMBIOS table for Type0, Bios Characteristics Extension 2, Bit3.

When I look at this bit in [RW Everything](http://rweverything.com/download/), I see that my firmware does support UEFI boot.

I'll add that SecureBoot and UEFI are not the same thing. SecureBoot is just a feature of the UEFI specification. I don't know of a way to check for SecureBoot support without booting in UEFI mode first.

[image: RW Everything Screenshot]